# Can you force a refresh token to expire in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, oauth-2.0

I have an application that uses Salesforce services using a Remote Access Application.  This is working fine so far.

However, my understanding is that even a refresh token will eventually expire, and I believe will return the following as part of a 404 (?):

```
"error_description":"expired access/refresh token"
```

My question is this: What is the best practice to test this scenario?  I obviously know that the normal refresh token flow is working fine, but how do I appropriately test the negative result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can login to the web interface and goto setup -> my personal information. one of the related lists on this page is called remote access, here you can see what refresh tokens have been issues, and revoke any of them.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had been looking all over in the setup and figured it would be in a menu link and I guess I had never bothered to just scroll down on the main page instead.

Comment: Hello @superfell, I can't see "my personal information" under set up. Is anything changed in 5.5 years?

Answer (score 0):

Go To the Setup and search for the apps
->Go to the connected apps under the managed apps
->select your app, there you can see the edit policies
->click on edit policies -> check for the refresh token policies under OAuth policies